# Liveload is not working and no source folder on webpack

Tags: android, visual-studio, ionic-framework, ionic4

I have an IONIC 4 app and using this command:

**ionic capacitor run android**

and after that I use

**ionic capacitor run android -l** ( for live loaded )

when I change something in VS CODE automatically compile and change in android, this is not working I don't know why, and when I go to **"chrome://inspect/#devices"** I see my device but I don't find any source map from my ts files, what I'm doing wrong?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is not yet supported with capacitor, as you can read in [ionic documentation](https://ionicframework.com/docs/cli/commands/capacitor-run)

> Once the web assets and configuration are copied into your native project, the app can run on devices and emulators/simulators using the native IDE. Unfortunately, programmatically building and launching the native project is not yet supported.

The fastest steps you can follow to reload your simulator:

1. Run `ng build --watch` through terminal, it will watch changes & rebuild project
2. In another terminal, after every ng build completion, manually run `ionic cap sync android`
3. Once sync is completed, in the Android Studio, rerun the project.

**NOTE**: The `livereload` only refreshes the `www` root folder, and thus refresh the ionic web version `http://localhost:8100`, but it doesn't sync those changes into android folder.

> **TIP:**
>   If your app doesn't have native plugins which will not work in browser version, or for testing use cases which are not dependent on native hardware, using `IONIC DEVAPP` comes very handy with livereload & testing on real devices.
>   https://ionicframework.com/docs/appflow/devapp